# Vue Auth - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' but he is there

Tags: vue.js, axios, vue-router, vue-cli

I want to make an authentication with Vue Auth, Axios and Cakephp but I have the well-known mistake:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://dev.zenburo.actuelburo.local:8081/api/users/token' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I also have the warning :

`Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response http://dev.zenburo.actuelburo.local:8081/api/users/token with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.`

The thing is, I dont have a content type 'text / html' and i have the header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Moreover, All other requests work on this API.

Here is my code :

Axios instance (@/api) :

```
import axios from 'axios'

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://dev.zenburo.actuelburo.local:8081/api/',
    timeout: 5000,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://localhost:8080/',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Access-Token',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credential': 'true',
    }
});
```

Vue Auth Config (@/auth) :

```
import bearer from '@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/auth/bearer'
import axios from '@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/http/axios.1.x'
import router from '@websanova/vue-auth/drivers/router/vue-router.2.x'

const config = {
    auth: bearer,
    http: axios,
    router: router,
    loginData: {
        url: '/users/token',
        redirect: '/dashboard',
        method: 'POST',
    }
};

export default config
```

main.js :

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import router from './routes'
import api from '@/api'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import auth from './auth'
import VueAuth from '@websanova/vue-auth'
import Index from './views/Index'
import ECharts from 'vue-echarts'
import store from './store'
import 'echarts/lib/chart/bar'
import 'echarts/lib/component/tooltip'
import 'echarts-gl'


window.Vue = Vue;
Vue.router = router

Vue.component('v-chart', ECharts);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
Vue.use(VueRouter);

Vue.use(VueAxios, api);

Vue.use(VueAuth, auth);

new Vue({
    vuetify,
    store,
    render: h => h(Index),
    router,
}).$mount('#app');
```

And finally, login.vue :

```
<template />

<script>
 export default {
        name: "Login",
        data() {
            return {
                account: '',
                password: '',
            }
        },
        methods: {
            login() {
                let self = this
                this.$auth.login({
                    body: {username: self.account, password: self.password},
                    method: 'POST',
                    rememberMe: true,
                    success: function () {
                        console.log('ok');
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        console.log(error)
                    },
                })
            }
        }
    }
<script/>
```

And this is the network without cache :

[image: REQUEST OPTIONS]

[image: REQUEST POST]

Is this a problem on the client or server side? (I repeat: all other methods except auth, works; so I have a doubt)

Does anyone have a solution?

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: How about preflight request? OPTIONS? It's working well?

Comment: @AlexisGatuingt, Those headers should be present in the response from your api, your api is telling your browser that the client website is allowed to make that request to your api. This is a conversation between your [api and browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)(known as preflight).

Answer (score 1):

Problem: Response Server Side.

you must return a response with Access-Control-Expose-Headers

```
header("Authorization: 'YOURTOKEN'");
```

Comment: After 2 days I finally found your answer and added Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Authorization" to my .htaccess

Many thanks

Comment: Hi @migli ! Can you please point me to how can i configure this Authorization on htaccess?

Comment: Here's a sample code:
`<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Authorization"
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, @Gander comment is very accurate.

It is a problem of preflight request (to pass in OPTIONS).

it happens often when you call a local API.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're mixing up request headers and response headers. e.g. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` should just be a response header but you're sending it both ways. Make sure you are clear about the difference between them and then check each header to ensure you are sending it in the correct direction.

Next, in the second picture it clearly shows that the response has a `Content-type` of `text/html`, consistent with the second error message. Again I stress it is important to understand the difference between the request headers and the response headers. The request also has a `Content-type` set but that is entirely separate.

The other error message states that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is missing. Remember, this is a response header, it doesn't count if you set it as a request header. In the first picture, for the pre-flight OPTIONS request, that header is present so all is well. It then attempts the POST request but this time the response does not contain that header, or any of the other CORS headers.

Given your other requests are working I suggest you contrast this with those other requests. I suspect you will see that the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` *response* header is present for those requests.